# How to get latitude longitude from google map URL

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am building an android application which would store latitude and longitude information from google maps. The application receives the Send/Share intent from Google maps when user chooses location from map and extracts co-ordinates by un-shortening the goo.gl map link (e.g. http://goo.gl/maps/FcglP) embedded in intent. This task is easy if the location being shared from google maps is unknown or named "dropped pin". In that case the un-shortened URL looks like

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=17.50122123,74.12351323&.....
```

If the location is well known (http://goo.gl/maps/FcglP), e.g. some road, un-shortened URL looks like

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=Sutarwadi+Baner+Gaon+Rd%2C+Baner&ftid=0x3bc2becfa70b8b3f:0xd210c15f634bcec3&hl=en&gl=us
```

I have been searching for last three hours about how to extract the co-ordinates from this kind of URL but couldn't find any information. Is there any other method to extract co-ordinates from a given goo.gl map URL? Some already developed library or google API?

Comment: I dont think so this is possible using Android Google Maps v2. try with Places API , ArcGIS Map or others

Comment: I tried Places API. No luck there. I don't think that ArcGIS would be helpful in the context.

Comment: this is not possible becoz here how could you get coordinates from this type of URL even?

Comment: Well, that is why the stackoverflow question :-)

Comment: Did you find an answer yet? ;)

Comment: Has anyone find a solution for same yet ?

Answer (score 4):

2 steps:

- Obtain a JSON with a long CID url by expanding the short URL: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expand
- Retrieve information with the given URL: <longURL>&output=json
   Then, in the final JSON, you've got a viewport section with a center lat&lon location

Comment: this works, but it means downloading 10k of data. Anyone know a way to parse the `ftid=` part for the lat/long?  It looks like it could be a lat/long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907305/get-latitude-longitude-from-url-google-maps/63842716#63842716

check this answer

Answer (score 0):

function myMap() {

```
var mapUrl = $('.map').html();
var url = mapUrl.split('@');
var at = url[1].split('z');
var zero = at[0].split(',');
var lat = zero[0];
var lon = zero[1];

var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        zoom:5,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapL"),mapProp);
```

}

Comment: Edit your original post