# Get latitude-longitude from URL Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-url-shortener

I need a way to figure out the latitude, longitude of a place in google map provided its link. Alternatively, it is fine if I can plot the point inside my application on a map, if possible, or share the latitude longitude from google map using some intent, so that I can receive it from within my application. Is any of the above possible directly or indirectly?

In short, I have a google map URL with me(which I may have received in WhatsApp or similar platform), and using that, somehow, I need to get the latitude and longitude of the place within my application, even if it is an indirect way. I am not interested in places API, since it having a limit.

Have been trying to get to a solution for a few hours, didn't find anything relevant.

**EDIT:**

Samples of link I am trying to use:

- https://goo[dot]gl/maps/fSQSTjDR32m
- https://maps.google.com/?cid=14927999966769665575&hl=en&gl=gb

(Not able to use URL shortners, since SO doesn't allow, replace [dot] with .)

Comment: Please give an example of such a link. Start your post with it.

Comment: update your questio and add  a proper url sample

Comment: Please check edit.

Answer (score 4):

Seems, there is no one common solution for all types of encoded URLs, but for described two you can use:

1) for URLs like `https://goo[dot]gl/maps/fSQSTjDR32m` - Google [URL Shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expand) with requests like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=<YOUR_SHORT_URL_e_g_https://goo[dot]gl/maps/fSQSTjDR32m>&key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>
```

NB! You need valid key for your Android app with enabled URL Shortener API  on [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/urlshortener.googleapis.com)

You can use `HttpURLConnection` to get response

```
...
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=...");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
```

or use [URL Shortener API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1). For more details take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18372672/6950238) question of [Ogre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504055/ogre) and answers.

So, for your shortened URL you should get JSON response like:

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "https://goo<.>gl/maps/fSQSTjDR32m",
 "longUrl": "https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/10%C2%B007'16.8%22N+76%C2%B020'54.2%22E/@10.1213253,76.3478427,247m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d10.1213237!4d76.348392?shorturl=1",
 "status": "OK"
}
```

where `longUrl` tag contains URL with desired latitude-longitude. According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/yvm0rlv6VZ8/hZUeVDMrCwAJ) answer of treebles:

> It is not the first set of coordinates@10.1213253,76.3478427 - that is
>   the center of the Maps' viewport. The coordinates of the point of
>   interest comes after their fid and is indicated by
>   !3d10.1213237!4d76.348392 Where the !3d parameter indicated the latitude and the !4d parameter indicates the longitude of the point of interest.

And you can find latitude-longitude in `longUrl` by `!3d` and `!4d` prefixes or using regular expression.

2) for URLs like https://maps.google.com/?cid=14927999966769665575&hl=en&gl=gb you can use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) and URL request like

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=&key=

where `<YOUR_CID> = 14927999966769665575` and `<YOUR_APP_KEY>` valid key for your Android app with enabled Google Maps API (on Developer Console same as for URL Shortener API). Fro more details take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49141701/6950238) answer of [Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9453170/leon).
You can use `HttpURLConnection` to get response like for point 1:

```
...
URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=...");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
```

and as the result you should get big JSON with tag `geometry` and "subtag" `location`

```
...
"geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 10.1652839,
        "lng" : 76.218744
     },
     "viewport" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 10.1666328802915,
           "lng" : 76.22009298029151
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 10.1639349197085,
           "lng" : 76.21739501970849
        }
     }
  },
...
```

and you can get latitude-longitude from it.

For other types URL (not https://goo[dot]gl/maps/fSQSTjDR32m nor     https://maps.google.com/?cid=14927999966769665575&hl=en&gl=gb) you should find other schemes for decoding and extracting  latitude-longitude.

Comment: "Google has shut down its URL shortening service. The existing links will continue to redirect to their intended destination" What other options do we have? As it's not possible to create such API key now

Comment: @a7md0 Seems HttpURLConnection still works. Or You can try to use browser..

Comment: I was looking to find it from the short-url

Comment: @a7md0 Short URLs like https://goo[dot]gl/maps/fSQSTjDR32m can be parsed by Web browser (try to open it on you desktop and it converted to something like that https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/10%C2%B007'16.8%22N+76%C2%B020'54.2%22E/@10.1213333,76.3483889,560m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d10.1213333!4d76.3483889?entry=ttu  and you can get it from url line of browser).

Comment: Seems you can get it even from HttpUrlConntection class.

Answer (score 1):

You can get latitude-longitude from URL Google Maps,

**with using Regex Matcher and Pattern**

**Note:** *This works fine without a short link, like this :*

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Egypt/@26.8444558,26.3722095,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x0:0x0!2zMTfCsDMwJzA0LjQiTiA3NMKwMDcnMjQuNyJF!3b1!8m2!3d17.5012212!4d74.1235132!3m4!1s0x14368976c35c36e9:0x2c45a00925c4c444!8m2!3d27.0982539!4d29.8828125

```
String url = "www.google.com/maps/place/@bla,bla"; // full link
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+,\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Now you will get latitude-longitude, I`f you want to split as two variable use this

```
if (matcher.find()) {
            String s = matcher.group(0);

            String lon = s.split(",")[0];
            String lat = s.split(",")[1];

            System.out.println(lon);
            System.out.println(lat);

        }
```